# Troubleshooting "Call to a member function on a non-object" when generating a single entity

Tags: symfony

I am studying symfony2 and make demo example for that.

When i am trying to run below command.

```
$php app/console doctrine:generate:entities HelloBundle
```

its works fine. but its generate all then entities.

but if i want to generate particular one entities then

```
$php app/console doctrine:generate:entities HelloBundle --entity="User"
```

it gives below error

```
$ php console doctrine:generate:entities HelloBundle --entity="Messages"
Generating entities for "HelloBundle"

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getShortName() on a non-object in /home/prakash/web/Symfony/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php on line 63
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a bug. Try reporting it to the Symfony Dev mailing list.

Comment: When i run this command it gives me error `The file name,directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect`.Can any1 help ??

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I've just been doing this!

It seems you're using Linux, so open up a Terminal, `cd` to Symfony's app directory, then run `./console --shell`.

This'll bring up the interactive shell where you can run through commands piecemeal, which I've found a little more helpful if not a bit slower.

When the shell is open, type `doctrine:generate:entity` and it'll run you through a little wizard where you can create a single entity for a specific bundle. It'll ask you first for the name, eg. `HelloBundle:EntityName`, then it'll ask for the syntax to use (yml, xml, annotation) and then it will let you enter the fields and their types.

After doing that (if you want), and hitting return when the field name is blank, it'll ask you if you want to generate the repository class for the entity, and finally make sure you want to generate it all. Hit return again and your entity files will be made.

I tried the single line command way as described in the OP but got strange errors (may have done it wrong), however it may be a simple case of taking that command and replacing `entities` with `entity`.

more info: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html